# How to write HTML correctly on DreamWeaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm using DreamWeaver to code and even though it structures CSS nicely automatically it doesn't do the same with HTML. What I mean is that instead of structuring the code as this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello People</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

It shows it as:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello People</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

How will I be able to form the HTML in a way like that automatically on DreamWeaver? Thank you on advance!

Comment: You should really search your problem on Google first, if that still hasnt solved your problem you can ask a question on StackOverflow.